# Call specific columns with regular expression pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas, I want to do something like this while looping through data frames:

```
    for body_part, columns in zip(self.body_parts, usecols_gen()):
        body_part_df = self.read_csv(usecols=columns)
        if self.normalize:
            body_part_df[r'x(\.\d)?'] = body_part_df[r'x(\.\d)?'].apply(lambda x: x/x_max)
        print(body_part_df)
        result[body_part] = body_part_df
```

I use regular expressions because the column names I refer to are mangled: x, x.1, x.2, ..., x.n

This gives KeyError, and I don't understand the reason. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query a `DataFrame` column using a regular expression, what you can do instead is iterate over it and apply your function on the matching columns, i.e.:

```
import re

    # ...

    for body_part, columns in zip(self.body_parts, usecols_gen()):
        body_part_df = self.read_csv(usecols=columns)
        if self.normalize:
            for column in body_part_df:
                if re.match(r"x(\.\d)?", column):  # or re.search() for partial matches
                    body_part_df[column] = body_part_df[column].apply(lambda x: x/x_max)
        print(body_part_df)
        result[body_part] = body_part_df
```

Comment: Should this be a future request? Or do you believe that it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Pandas is trying to play nice with PEP standards so accessing a `DataFrame` column is much like accessing a dictionary - it's intended to be deterministic, final and fast. You can always use [`pandas.DataFrame.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to get only the columns you're interested in (i.e. `body_part_df.filter(regex=r"x(\.\d)?", axis=1)` in your case) but in this instance you might as well filter it yourself given that you also want to update the data as you go along. Such cases are too rare to warrant a specific feature, IMO.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your time