# Can I pass a regex to pandas index_col

Tags: python, pandas

I have a diversity of data files to load where the column names are not consistent.

Ideally I would pass to `pd.read_csv(file, index_col = 'patient_id')`

But in the data I find columns names for the id like `'patien_id','pat_id'` etc.

So I thought passing some kind of regex would be nice. Any idea?

Best

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52403401/5532710) you cannot query a dataframe column with regex.

Comment: @CarloZanocco a column name is just a string?

Comment: Yes, a column **name** is just a string. The DataFrame column is a Series object.

Answer (score 2):

You could try filtering the columns in your Pandas dataframe using regex:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)              # read entire CSV into dataframe
df = df.filter(regex=("pat.*_id"))  # subset dataframe to only the columns you want
```

Comment: so this would be passed to index_col? this would mean re-loading?

Comment: @MarioL I am suggesting to first load the entire data frame from the CSV file, then retain only the columns in which you are interested.

Comment: I see, its a solution. Nevertheless, I hoped it would be possible to do it at loading within pd.read_csv()

Comment: CSV loading tools with most languages (including Pandas, SQL, and R, to name a few) behave this way; you would tend to load the whole CSV into Pandas and then figure out what to do with it.